# java inner class function calling with button listener

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, drawing

So I have a button listener that is external in scope to the function `setPaintFlag()` and I need to call it, but java is giving me runtime errors. In addition my drawing panel is not showing up. Can anyone spot my mistake? the purpose of the program is to draw either a circle or a square in a random position with a random size and a color. The program compiles and the window will show up, only the buttons are visible but they do not fire. the error visible when i hover over the `setPaintFlag()` is `The method setPaintFlag(int) is undefined for the type PaintLab.buttonListener`

A more verbose error message after a button press is

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method setPaintFlag(int) is undefined for the type PaintLab.ButtonListener
    The method setPaintFlag(int) is undefined for the type PaintLab.ButtonListener`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintLab extends JPanel {
    private JButton circle, square;
    private JPanel drawingPanel;

    public PaintLab() {
        circle = new JButton("Draw Circle");
        circle.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        square = new JButton("Draw Square");
        square.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);
        add(drawingPanel);
        BoxLayout bX = new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(bX);
        buttonPanel.add(circle);
        buttonPanel.add(square);

        add(buttonPanel);

    }

    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel { // outer
        private boolean paintFlag = false;
        private int theMode = -1;
        private int width, height;

        private DrawingPanel(int width, int height) { // inner
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void setPaintFlag(int current) { // inner
            paintFlag = true;
            theMode = current;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // inner
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            int gn = (int) (Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            g2.setColor(new Color(r, gn, b));
            int w = (int) (Math.random() * width) + 1;
            int h = (int) (Math.random() * height) + 1;
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * width) + 1;
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * height) + 1;

            if (theMode == 0) {
                g2.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
                g2.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
            } else if (theMode == 1) {
                g2.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
                g2.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            if (event.getSource() == circle) {
                setPaintFlag(0);
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            } else if (event.getSource() == square) {
                setPaintFlag(1);
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the main.

```
    public class paintLabMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Paint Lab");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (300,600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new PaintLab());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Please post a [MCVE]. 2.Where di you call `buttonListener` ? 3. What errors do you get ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my main. The program compiles and the window will show up, only the buttons are visible but they do not fire.

Comment: The buttons don't fire because they have no action listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons don't fire because they have no action listener:

```
Circle = new JButton("Draw Circle")
Circle.addActionListener(new buttonListener())
```

The error message is because you call `setPaintFlag(int current)` form `ButtonListener` but it is defined in `DrawingPanel`.

**Edit:** 
Please see comments (The code can't compile because I removed parts of it and left a skeleton):

```
    public class PaintLab extends JPanel {
    private JButton circle, square;
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;//declare drawingPanel as field 

    public PaintLab() {
        circle = new JButton("Draw Circle");
        circle.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        square = new JButton("Draw Square");
        square.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        /*JPanel already declared as field*/  
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);
        add(drawingPanel);
        BoxLayout bX = new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(bX);
        buttonPanel.add(circle);
        buttonPanel.add(square);

        add(buttonPanel);
    }

    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel { // outer

            //code removed
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // inner
            //code removed     
        }

        //add setters 
        void setPaintFlag(boolean paintFlag) {
            this.paintFlag = paintFlag;
        }

        void setTheMode(int theMode) {
            this.theMode = theMode;
        }
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            if (event.getSource() == circle) {
                drawingPanel.setPaintFlag(true);
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            } else if (event.getSource() == square) {
                drawingPanel.setPaintFlag(false);
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Made your changes, `setPaintFlag` still is throwing errors but the buttons are firing now. thank you

Comment: Appreciate the help very much, you've resolved all the errors and the program is working.

Comment: The code won't compile - you can't have methods in methods

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer. I fixed it (just a copy paste error). The code can't compile because I removed parts of it and left a skeleton.